# Add element to multi row array with angular / javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I have the following array with data:

```
[
{"count":1,"title":"Ark: Survival","platform":"Playstation PS4"},
{"count":2,"title":"Lara Croft:", "platform":"Playstation PS4"},
{"count":1,"title":"Madden NFL", "platform":"Playstation PS4"}
]
```

All in my angular Cart scope:

```
var data = $scope.cart;
```

now i would like to add to each row the order number, so i use a push:

```
$scope.cart.push({"orderNumber": $scope.OrderNumber});
```

the problem is that is adds the order number but as a separate row and not inside each of the rows. so my desired output should look like this:

```
[
{"count":1,"title":"Ark: Survival","platform":"Playstation PS4","orderNumber":1 },
{"count":2,"title":"Lara Croft:", "platform":"Playstation PS4","orderNumber":1},
{"count":1,"title":"Madden NFL", "platform":"Playstation PS4","orderNumber":1}
]
```

how would i push to each row of the array? i tried several versions but can't seem to get it to work.

Answer (score 1):

You need to iterate over each item and add the `orderNumber` as a property for each item. So you can use `forEach` function of the `angular` for that.

```
angular.forEach($scope.cart, (item) => item.orderNumber = $scope.OrderNumber)
```

Answer (score 1):

in order to achieve that you should iterate through each object and set order number separately

```
angular.forEach($scope.cart, function (value, key) {
    value.orderNumber = $scope.OrderNumber;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

just got an answer that i implemented but the user has deleted the response, however it works perfect, this was the solution that i used:

```
$scope.cart.forEach(item => item.orderNumber = $scope.OrderNumber)
```